# What to give the weird guy who talks of darkness?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So I just wondered my way to huntsman's copse and there is this guy who just talks about his obsession to darkness but say if 'you have the gift' he'll do something, what exactly so I give the guy?

Answer (score 8):

That's [Felkin the Outcast](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Felkin+the+Outcast). He likes Hexes.

If you have 8 INT and 8 FTH, he'll let you purchase some hexes and useful items.

If you have 20 INT and 20 FTH, he'll give you the [Hexer Set](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Hexer+Set) and the [Sunset Staff](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Sunset+Staff) after you completely exhaust his conversation options.

(A note on the Fextralife wiki also seems to indicate that you may also need to kill all of the bosses in the Huntsman's Copse before he'll give you the armor and staff, but I can't verify that.)

Comment: We'll that suck because I'm a knight, not a sorcerer

Comment: @Gyhome The items are really only useful to magic-using characters anyway. If you don't use magic at all, then you haven't missed out on much.